# How to resolve clipboard error while deploying vuejs app on ubuntu server

Tags: vue.js, npm, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

I am deploying a vuejs app on my server.we have EC2 instance with ubuntu 16.04,As of now I am just deploying my test project but when I go running serve command like `sudo serve -s dist`  but it is throwing an error which is: `ERROR: Cannot copy to clipboard: Command failed: xsel --clipboard --input
xsel: Can't open display: (null)
: Inappropriate ioctl for device`

I don't know this error is caused by ubuntu or vuejs please help me solve it.

I have followed these cammands so far.

First installed vue cli using 
`npm install -g @vue/cli`

Then created a hello world app using 
`vue create helloWorld`

Now run serve command 
`npm run serve`

It was showing me a message like:

`App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8081/ 
  - Network: http://172.31.16.66:8081/`

Now i have created a build to run an app on the production server
`npm run build`

So my build was created successfully 
i run command to run the app on the live server

`serve -s dist`

And it is throwing an error which is not solving by me so far

`WARNING: Checking for updates failed (use`--debug`to see full error)
ERROR: Cannot copy to clipboard: Command failed: xsel --clipboard --input
xsel: Can't open display: (null)
: Inappropriate ioctl for device`

I am also attaching screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, there is an X11 dependency with the `serve` module - which means you need an xserver(display) for it to work.

Alternatively, (**highly recommended**) you could use a high performance HTTP server like **nginx**, **apache** etc. instead.

All you need is to copy your dist folder to your instance, and point your virtual server block to the `dist` dir, and restart your HTTP server - BAM! you're up and running.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved it by adding "-n" option to serve.

"-n, --no-clipboard Do not copy the local address to the clipboard"